# Error: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined/a /at NodeList.forEach)/at HTMLSelectElement.filterTodo

Tags: javascript, child-nodes

**Error**:

```
 1. script.js:153 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of
    undefined
        at script.js:153
        at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at HTMLSelectElement.filterTodo (script.js:150)
```

**Code**:

```
enter code here function filterTodo(e) {
let todos = todoList.childNodes;
todos.forEach(function(todo) {
  switch (e.target.value) {
    case "all":
      todo.style.display = "flex";
      break;
    case "completed":
      if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
        todo.style.display = "flex";
      } else {
        todo.style.display = "none";
      }
      break;
    case "uncompleted":
      if (!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
        todo.style.display = "flex";
      } else {
        todo.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are selecting `let todos = todoList.childNodes;` make sure there is not any space between `todoList` element.
for example:

```
var todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
```

Correct:

```
<ul class="todo-list"></ul>
```

Error:

```
<ul class="todo-list>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check what is `todos` contains. 
You try to assign `undefined.style.display = 'something'`

Comment: yes but i already give todos as a var  of  todoList.childNodes

Answer (score 0):

You could have non element  inside todos,

> childNodes includes all child nodes—including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes. To get a collection of only elements, use ParentNode.children instead. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

Comment: thank you i just figure out that i forget an end of an element back in HTML

Comment: that makes sense. That'll damage the `childNodes`.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the space in `ul` tag it will work.